# Hyperbolic / Radial Tree Layout Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, layout, tree, radial

I need to obtain the (x,y) coordinates for rendering a Tree data structure made up of single nodes.
I know there are some algorithms for example:

[Wikipedia: Radial Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_tree)

[Wikipedia: Hyperbolic Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_tree)

My Tree looks like this:

```
TreeNode=function(data,parent){
this.data=data;
this.parent=parent;
this.children=[];
return this;
};
TreeNode.prototype.addChild=function(data){
this.children.push(new TreeNode(data,this));
return this;
};
```

How ever, I cant seem to figure out how to implement these algorithms or any library that does that for me.

I am using an HTML Canvas to draw the nodes with Javascrypt.
Now i need the position of each node acoording to one of the stated before algorithms.

How can I implement this algorithm?
Is there any library I can use?

Comment: Here's an example of the D3 library displaying a radial tree layout http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/tree.html

Comment: I know, the problem is, I need the coordinates, that library already draw it for me on the screen, I need only the position to output it on a .txt file